# Electronitc switch without common contact

Tags: transistors

As I understand it, a transistor can be schematically described as a variable resistor controlled by a tension (when it is correctly biased). That is, the resistance between emitter and collector is regulated by the difference of potential between base and emitter. However, the "regulating circuit" and the "controlled circuit" must share a contact (the collector).

Is there a component or a simple circuit with four contacts that implements something similar to a transistor, but without requiring that the two circuits share a contact? So I would like to have something such that the potential difference between contacts A and B controls the resistance between C and D, without requiring that (for instance) A and C have the same potential.

One could probably do something like that with a relay or by optically coupling a LED with a phototransistor; however, I wonder whether this can be done in a purely electronic way.

[I ultimately need this component for coupling two circuits that may have different grounds; probably they actually do not, but I would like to avoid relying on that; and I am also interested in the abstract question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a linear relation between input and output voltage, you could consider an isolation amplifier.

A two-port isolation amplifier has the power supply common to one side (input or output, depending on amplifier) with the other side galvanically isolated from that side.

A three-port isolation amplifier has galvanic isolation between all three ports: the input, output and power supply can each have separate ground references.

Answer (score 5):

The component you are looking for is called an opto-coupler (or opto-isolator).

Essentially it is as you suggest in your question, an LED and a Phototransistor built into a single package. You drive the LED and the phototransistor turns on and off depending on whether the LED is lit or not.

Below is the symbol for an opto-coupler:

[image: Opto-coupler Symbol]

Essentially 1 and 2 are the input which could be something like a microcontroller I/O pin (e.g. 1 would go to the pin, 2 to GND). Then 3 and 4 are the output which is completely isolated from the input. Current will flow from the collector to emitter of the phototransistor when the LED is illuminated.

Comment: They are also made with a photoresistor instead of a phototransistor - useful for optically isolated gain control.

Comment: Indeed, all transistors (BJT's, FETs, Vacuum Tubes...) are fundamentally 3-terminal devices that operate in principle via an E-field potential barrier that controls a current. For isolation you have to look to other avenues, such as light and magnetism.

Answer (score 1):

A transistor is more like a current sink that is controlled by the voltage between base and emitter (the base current also increases exponentially with the base voltage).

A phototransistor optoisolator is a bit like a transistor with an isolated B-E junction, but for some reason you say you don't think that's electronic enough..

If there are different grounds there are a variety of ways of getting the signal across an isolation barrier or a potential difference. If it's a more-or-less fixed difference, simply using a level shifter (for example, a current source to send the signal and a resistor to receive it) might do the trick. Other methods include transformers and small differential capacitors. Sometimes safety is a concern, and in such cases regulatory rules often come into play. Without **detailed** information on the exact application it's hard to give any kind of useful guidance on which of the many methods might be applicable.